# R-Forge: binary not provided

Tags: r, r-forge

I am hosting a package on R-Forge and the status is 0 - Current.
When installing it in R with install.packages the following message appears:

> package is available as a source package but not as a binary

With the additional option type="source" it can be installed, but how can I also provide the binary and why is the binary not provided?

Thanks a lot!

Best,

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Important note for package binaries: R-Forge provides these binaries only for the most recent version of R, but not for older versions. In order to successfully install the packages provided on R-Forge, you have to switch to the most recent version of R or, alternatively, install from the package sources (.tar.gz)."

So, updating to the newest version of R works and provides the binaries.